# Connecting to Docker Container Network from the Client Side

Tags: php, laravel, docker, websocket, docker-network

I have two containers, a php server serving a laravel application and a spring boot application running a websocket server. My architecture was to connect the two containers using Docker Networking and have the Laravel container port published to the outside. The laravel application is pretty much all front end, and on one page is a chat room using websocket. I tried to connect the chat room to the Spring Boot websocket container name (Docker network) but I feel like because this request is coming from the client this is not possible? I am using the container name (domain name) as a URL on the javascript file that is being served by the php server. Would the only way to make this work is publish the Spring Boot port as well on a public server and replace the websocket url with a public url?

Comment: This looks more like a network configuration issue rather than a programming specific question (at the moment anyway).

Comment: @NigelRen It kind of depends, because it is more a Docker related question and since Docker seems to be a legitimate topic on Stack Overflow, I don't see why this question would be off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Additional info like docker-compose or commands you are running would also be helpful.

But from what I see, the issue probably is that the requests are coming from the client which means that they can't access the actual service since it's not available publicly...

You should probably make that service available as well by mapping the necessary ports to your host machine or create some proxy server to pass the requests to the websocket